# Swap two variables in Elisp

Tags: elisp

Suppose I have

```el
(setq a 1 b 2)
```

How can I elegantly swap the values of `a` and `b` without using a temporary variable?

Comment: While I remember the swap operation from programming examples many many years ago, I don't think I've ever needed such a "swap" operation.  So where do you find you need such a thing?

Comment: @Stefan this time, I'm writing a function that takes two arguments, and I'd like to ensure that the first argument is the smaller of the two.

Comment: @PythonNut, well you can bind first argument to `(min a b)` and second to `(max a b)`. This is one solution. Some will argue that this requires two comparisons when one suffices, that's right. You can handle it with one comparison in more functional manner still, for example using destructuring bind `(cl-destructuring-bind (a . b) (if (< a b) (cons a b) (cons b a)) ...)`. This is another way.

Comment: @Mark true, but, at least to me, that feels like swatting flies with hand grenades. `cl-destructuring-bind` is a ridiculously powerful tool for this job.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If memory serves me well and you're willing to use `cl-lib` then:

```
(cl-rotatef a b)
```

Note that this is Common Lisp way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 21):

This is the elegant idiom I use ;-).

```
(setq a  (prog1 b (setq b  a)))
```

Comment: Hey, that's neat. I'll keep it in mind if performance is ever a concern.

Comment: Ingenious and simple.

Comment: Oh, it's not original with me, by any means. But it is probably the main use I make of `prog1`.

Comment: That's pretty much what `cl-rotatef` macro expands to.

Answer (score 6):

If it's integers:

```
(setq a (logxor a b))
(setq b (logxor a b))
(setq a (logxor a b))
```

:)

Comment: For completeness you should also include the following classic: a = a + b, b = a - b, a = a - b. Translated to Emacs Lisp, of course :-D

Comment: True, and for completeness I'll point out that in asm or C the The XOR Trick works for anything; registers, memory, ints, floats, structs, strings(equal length)... In Lisp I think only ints. For large blocks of memory it's nice to not need the temp buffer.

Comment: @jtgd: For large blocks of memory, you can do the swap segment-by-segment, with a small buffer.

Comment: @MarkKarpov: `(let* ( (a (+ a b))  (b (- a b))  (a (- a b)) )  … )`